# How to use mbregex on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

in order to use mPDF on Heroku I need to add mbregex to PHP. Does anybody know how to enable mbregex on Heroku?

When googling it, I'm not able to find any solution. I cannot believe nobody encountered this problem before.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide enough information. The problem is: I'm lost. I already contacted the Heroku support, which advised me to ask the community. From my point of view there is no possibility to enable mbregex on the Heroku buildscript for PHP. I can't find any buildscript which provides mbregex.

Is the only solution to write a buildscript on my own? I don't think I'm capable of doing so.

Thanks for your support. I don't want anybody to write code for me, I just have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I've also suddenly just run into this error - I've been running MPDF on heroku for some time but for some reason this error has started to crop up lately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change was made in [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/commit/5ed1d6033f78e3b367eb6d6831ec49d36bcfe3cc#diff-67f197bdc7022b09138971d7410b96d5R117) commit to the Heroku PHP Buildpack (which is how you run PHP on Heroku) which prevented `mbregex` being used in PHP versions 7.4 or later because `libonig` wasn't available.

[Version 172](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/pull/394) of the Heroku PHP Buildpack is nearly ready for release and re-enables mbstring regex on PHP 7.4 for 7.4.3. [This is scheduled for release today](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/pull/394/commits/ca582f9ce2f928b52fa842c18b531880337a89d2) all being well so in all likelihood if you try pushing to heroku tomorrow this will resolve the problem

Comment: @pipo92 v172 has now been released which fixes this issue